# Alternative implementation of `if` - incomprehensible behavior

Tags: if-statement, macros, lisp, common-lisp, ccl

I wanted to write my own `if` using Boolean logic and macros. I came up with the following implementation:

```
(defmacro -if (condition if-true if-false)
  "Implements `if` in terms of Boolean logic only"
  `(or (and ,condition ,if-true)
       (and (not ,condition) ,if-false)))
```

I tested it manually on several cases and it works as expected. But then I wrote a simple test function to perform a series of tests and got one result I still cannot understand. I wrote the function like this:

```
(defun -if-test ()
  (let ((passed 0)
    (test-format "TEST: ~50a ==> ~:[FAILURE~;SUCCESS~]~%")
    (cases '((return-value (> 2 1) true)
         (return-value (< 2 1) false)
         (standard-output (> 2 1) "true")
         (standard-output (< 2 1) "false"))))
    (dolist (test-case cases)
      (destructuring-bind (type test expected) test-case
    (let ((result (case type
            (return-value
             (eq (-if test 'true 'false) expected))
            (standard-output
             (with-output-to-string (out)
               (string= (-if test (print "true" out) (print "false" out)) expected)))
            (otherwise (error "Unknown test type: ~a" type)))))
      (when result (incf passed))
      (format t test-format test-case result))))
    (format t "Result: ~a/~a tests passed.~%" passed (length cases))))
```

When I run the tests I get the following output:

```
TEST: (RETURN-VALUE (> 2 1) TRUE)                        ==> SUCCESS
TEST: (RETURN-VALUE (< 2 1) FALSE)                       ==> FAILURE
TEST: (STANDARD-OUTPUT (> 2 1) true)                     ==> SUCCESS
TEST: (STANDARD-OUTPUT (< 2 1) false)                    ==> SUCCESS
Result: 3/4 tests passed.
NIL
```

The second failing case apparently gives different results when run by hand than when run as part of this function. I tried debugging it with SLDB and indeed the result is different from standalone execution. I suspect I missed some crucial execution detail or something like that. Can someone explain to me what happens here? Help really appreciated.

P.S. My implementation is Clozure CL.

Answer (score 2):

Your test cases are data. What you feed to `-if` isn't the evaluation of `(< 2 1)` but the list with `<`, `2` and `1` as elements. Anything but `nil` is a truth value so if you want to test what you do try: `(-if '(< 2 1) 'true 'false) ;==> true`.

So in this case your test was faulty. There is an error in your macro though:

```lisp
(-if (progn (print "ONLY ONE TIME!") x) nil t)
; ==> (not x), but it prints "ONLY ONE TIME!" twice!
```

When making a macro you should always ensure arguments are only evaluated one time, that the order in which they are evaluated are in the argument order because a commonlisper would expect that and that code will not fail no matter what symbols the user uses. The last one calls for use of `gensym` to ensure hygiene.

To fix your macro error you need to expand to a let form that evaluates the predicate so that the side effects won't be done twice. The name of this variable must be made unique with `gensym` or a macro that uses `gensym` like `only-once` or `with-gensyms` from popular books. An excellent book is [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) which is free to read and it has a part about macros and [common errors and how to fix them](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-defining-your-own.html)

Comment: `gensym` isn't really needed here, though, because the second evaluation of the condition is simply unnecessary. When you already know that `,condition` is false, there's no need to check that `(not ,condition)` is true.

Comment: @Rörd Give me a `defmacro` that still uses boolean logic and that doesn't need the predicate twice? test with `(if t nil t)`

Comment: That fact that some other construct is also used doesn't mean it doesn't used boolean logic anymore, right? So this would work: `(defmacro -if (test then else) \`(block nil (or (and ,test (return ,then)) ,else)))`

Comment: On second though, I see how it isn't "purely boolean logic" anymore the way it was before. I would still still allow my change here to shield against that edge case of a false-ish consequent.

Comment: @Rörd It's clever. I think it's better than ``(defmacro -if (p c a) (once-only (p) `(or (and ,p ,c) (and (not ,p) ,a))))``

Answer (score 2):

Your `-if-test` code does not work at all.

```
CL-USER 18 > (pprint (macroexpand '(-if test 'true 'false)))

(LET ((#:OR-SUBFORM-RESULT1129 (AND TEST 'TRUE)))
  (IF #:OR-SUBFORM-RESULT1129
     #:OR-SUBFORM-RESULT1129
    (OR (AND (NOT TEST) 'FALSE))))

CL-USER 19 > (let ((test '(> 2 1))) (-if test 'true 'false))
TRUE

CL-USER 20 >  (let ((test '(< 1 2))) (-if test 'true 'false))
TRUE
```

Your code does not test the condition. It tries to test if the variable `test` is true or false.

If you write a macro and use it, you need to check the code generation, first.

- does the generated code look like you want to?
- are things done more than once in the generated code?
- are things done in the right order in the generated code?
- are there variables or function symbols which should not be in the generated code?
- are my macro arguments processed correctly?

Also the way to check the test results does not do what you want. You do a `STRING=` to the result of the `-IF` expression. Not with the output. Also: `with-output-to-string` returns a string - always. The value of `result` is then this string. `(when result <do-this>)` then runs `<do-this>`, since result is a string, which is always true. In Common Lisp every value, other than NIL, is true.

Generally, if you really want to test a macro with different arguments, you actually need to run the macro expansion. Thus you need to generate the code at test time and run `EVAL` on it.

Comment: "Also the way to check the test results **does not do want you.**" I cannot understand this sentence, what should it say?

Comment: @nrz: fixed in the text